# C++: Return a lambda expression from a function that captures parameter of the function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

The following function is supposed to take the coefficients of a polynomial and create a function of time from them:

```
std::function<double(double)> to_equation(const std::vector<double>& coefficients)
{
    return [coefficients](double t)
    {
        auto total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.size(); i++)
        {
            total += coefficients[i] * pow(t,i);
            return total;
        }
    };
}
```

It should be usable as follows:

```
std::vector<double> coefficients = {1.0,2.0,3.0};
auto f = to_equation(coefficients);
auto value = f(t);
```

The code does however not work as intended, since at the time of execution of `f(t)`, not the coefficients passed to `to_equation(coefficients)` are used, but some totally different values magically captured from the context. What is happening and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are returning  a lambda that capture `coefficients` by value. If you pass some vector to the `to_equation` function, all values will be copied, and the lambda won't refer to the original vector anymore.

I suggest this solution:

```
// auto is faster than std::function
auto to_equation(const std::vector<double>& coefficients)
{
    // Here, you capture by reference.
    // The lambda will use the vector passed in coefficients
    return [&coefficients](double t)
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

However, you must sometime deal with code like this:

```
std::function<double(double)> f;

{
    std::vector<double> coeff{0.2, 0.4, 9.8};

    f = to_equation(coeff);
}

auto result = f(3);
```

This is bad, the vector `coeff` don't live long enough, and we refer to it after the vector is destroyed.

I suggest adding this overload to your function:

```
// when a vector is moved into coefficients, move it to the lambda
auto to_equation(std::vector<double>&& coefficients)
{
    // Here, you capture by value.
    // The lambda will use it's own copy.
    return [coeff = std::move(coefficients)](double t)
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Then, calling your function is possible in both ways:

```
std::vector<double> coeff{0.2, 0.4, 9.8};

auto f1 = to_equation(coeff); // uses reference to coeff
auto f2 = to_equation({0.2, 0.4, 9.8}) // uses value moved into the lambda
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture by reference, instead of by value. But, of course, if the underlying vector goes out of scope and gets destroyed before the lambda gets invoked, you'll have a big mess on your hands.

The safest course of action is to use a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>` instead of a plain vector, and capture that by value. Then, the lambda will always, essentially, feed on whatever were the most recent set of coefficients, and won't blow up if it gets called after all other references to the underlying vector, from whatever code computed them, go out of scope.

(Of course, you have to keep in mind what's going to happen here if the lambda gets copied around, since all copies of the original lambda will be using the same vector).

For more information, open the chapter of your C++ book that explains the difference between capturing by value and by reference, when using lambdas.